# Windows phone isolated storage for game saving in runnig condition

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to store my windows phone game in position where i left it last time (Pause situation). After resuming that game can i use that game from the last position where i left it.I'm using silver-light's API.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to manage the [tombstone state](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190204/Managing-Tombstone-State-in-a-Windows-Phone-7-Appl). How to manage the isolated storage is discribed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).